# Very high memory requirements for power simulations using the R function simr::powerSim

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I'm trying to do a power analysis for a project where we expect 40,000 observations (at least) across 40-60 "units".

When I do this power analysis using a much smaller number of observations within units (say, 100 per unit), the simulation runs fine. However, memory requirements seem to explode when I up the observations per unit to 300 or 500. I haven't been able to get the simulation to run even on a computer with a memory limit of 70GB.

What's going on? Why are the memory requirements so high and how would I make them more manageable?

The generic power simulation script is below, for reference.

```
#psacr001_power.R: Run a job using specifications determined using a shell script

#Get the arguments passed from the shell script
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
job <- as.numeric(args[[1]])
sample_size <- as.numeric(args[[2]])
number_of_labs <- as.numeric(args[[3]])
icc_size <- as.numeric(args[[4]])
slope_size <- as.numeric(args[[5]])
effect <- as.numeric(args[[6]])

#Required R libraries
library(lme4)
library(simr)
library(pbkrtest)
library(tibble)

#create dataset
simulated.df <- tibble(
                       x = sample(rep(0:1, sample_size * number_of_labs / 2)), #group assignment
                       g = rep(1:number_of_labs, sample_size), #number of clusters
                       y = rnorm(sample_size * number_of_labs) #outcome
                      )

#Create simple model
model.of.interest <- lmer(y ~ x + (x|g), data=simulated.df)

#Create a small effect of interest
fixef(model.of.interest)['x'] <- effect

#create various ICC intercept
VarCorr(model.of.interest)["g"][["g"]][1] <- icc_size

#create varioous slopes
VarCorr(model.of.interest)["g"][["g"]][4] <- slope_size

#try not to be singular
attr(VarCorr(model.of.interest)[["g"]], "correlation")[2:3] <- .3

power_summary <- tibble(
                        job = numeric(),
                        successes = numeric(),
                        trials = numeric(),
                        mean = numeric(),
                        lower = numeric(),
                        upper = numeric()
                       )

#simulate those models
temp <- powerSim(fit = model.of.interest,
                 nsim = 200,
                 progress=FALSE
                )

power_summary[1 , 1] <- job
power_summary[1 , 2:6] <- summary(temp)

write.csv(power_summary, paste(c("res_", job, ".csv"), collapse=""), row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Did you try to use `profvis` to understand at which step within `powerSim` memory needs explode ?

Comment: Nope. Got a link to resources on profvis?

Comment: You can have a look at [this website](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/). This will decompose every step of your callstack and show the resources needed by each

Comment: Terrific, thank you for the suggestion!